# Why is my component stuck in a re-rendering loop?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, jsx

I'm working on a component that displays an attachment that is either a pdf or a link. If it's a pdf, I'll display a pdf_bg image and the tile will link to the download page. And if it's a link I'll display the link_bg and the tile will link to the site.

For a while, my problems centered around getting the right data into "url". Without the right usage of async/await, my downloadurl was being successfully loaded but my component was still rendering an empty  tag. Eventually I set up the hooks you see here. So now the urls are correctly loading but for some reason the background image isn't getting set.

More critically, I get an error about too many re-renders. I know that the state hook has certain re-rendering behavior when it's updated. I thought the conditional I have set up would address that, but apparently not.

Any advice?

```
export default function AttachmentTile(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const attachHandler = attachmentUploader();
    let bgimage;
    let name = props.attInfo[0];
    //for files, the 1st index is the name, 2nd is the ID. for links, 1st is the name but 2nd is the link url
    let attID = props.attInfo[1];
    let type = props.attInfo[2];
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getUrl() {
            const downloadUrl = await attachHandler.getDownloadUrl(props.objID, attID);
            setUrl(downloadUrl);
        }
        if(url === null && type === "file")
            getUrl();
    });


    if(props.attachmentImage){
        bgimage = props.attachmentImage;
    }else if(type === "file"){
        bgimage = pdf_bg;
    }else if(type === "link"){
        bgimage = link_bg;
        //in this case, attID isn't actually an ID, it's the url we store for links.
        setUrl(attID);
    }

    if(url === null){
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }
     return ( AttachmentTile component that uses {url} in an <a> tag  )
```

Comment: your `useEffect` doesn't have a dependency array which means that it fires every time the component renders; that could be causing it since it also updates state.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your useEffect function to include dependency as shown

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function getUrl() {
            const downloadUrl = await attachHandler.getDownloadUrl(props.objID, attID);
            setUrl(downloadUrl);
        }
        if(url === null && type === "file")
            getUrl();
    },[]);
```

Comment: Adding a dependency seems like the right route. However, I'm still getting an error about too many re-renderings.